# How can I divide a RXJS Observable stream into equal N sized arrays?

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

Let's say I have an Observable stream created from an array like so:

```
const items: Items = [{},{},{},{},{},...];
const obs$ = from(items).pipe(
    mergeMap(items => {
        return this.getData(items);
    })
);
```

As this code stands, `getData()` will be called for each item in the array. What I want to do is divide the items array into N equal sized arrays, then have those arrays emitted instead. Then `getData()` will be called with the individual arrays rather than each item in the original items array.

Basically I need a variation of the `toArray()` operator but on only portions of the stream that I pre-define.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need buffer operator which has several variations, which are: `buffer, bufferCount, bufferTime, bufferToggle, bufferWhen`. [Buffer Official Documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html)

**For example in your case dividing array in 3 size arrays would be:**

```
const items: Items = [{},{},{},{},{},...];
const obs$ = from(items).pipe(
    bufferCount(3),
    mergeMap(items => {
        return this.getData(items);
    })
);
```